# shell script is stop after SSH (logged into kubernetes pod)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, kubernetes

Here my `shell` script in my `host`.

```
#!/bin/bash
loginCommend="kubectl -n my-namespace exec -it my-demo-app-58df8dc87-568gb /bin/bash"
eval "$loginCommend"
ls -la
```

My shell script is stop after `eval "$loginCommend"`.

Which mean `shell script` is stop after `changing/ssh` to another host, I think. I would like to do continuous running `ls -la`.

Comment: Why dont you run `kubectl -n my-namespace exec -it my-demo-app-58df8dc87-568gb "ls -la"` ??

Comment: `eval` is a huge bug magnet; I recommend avoiding it whenever possible. Do you really need to put the `kubectl` command in a variable instead of just executing it directly? If you do, see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @Gordon Davisson thank for your point. I will try another way